# JQuery validator plugin passing data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with JQuery validator being applied to it.  I wont post it all, but the code looks like the following

```
var validator = $("#my_form").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        $( element )
            .closest( "form" )
                .find( "#error" )
                    .append( error );
    },
    rules: {
        emailAddress: {
          require_from_group: [1, '.datagroup'],
          email: true,
          maxlength: 40
        },
        mobileNumber: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.datagroup'],
            number:true,
            minlength: 8
        }
    },
    messages: {
        emailAddress: {
            maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("shorter")
        },
        mobileNumber: {
            number: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a number"),
            minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a valid number")
        }
    },
    groups: {
        datagroup: "emailAddress mobileNumber"
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "php/main.php",
             data: $(form).serialize()
         })
         .done(function (response) {
             $('#results').html(response)
        });
         return false;
     }
});
```

The problem is that the submit handler is passed the whole form, and then this data is serialized and sent to main.php.  However,I no longer want the format it is submitting the mobileNumber in.  The reason for this is that I am now using a plugin which will format this number for me, and to get the value of this, I need to do

```
var mobileNumber = $("#mobileNumber").intlTelInput("getNumber");
```

I can also grab the email using val() so this can be assigned to a variable as well.  So how can I pass main.php the variables mobileNumber and emailAddress?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do so, by manually constructing the data object like below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/main.php",
    data: {
        'emailAddress': $("#mobileNumber").intlTelInput("getNumber"),
        'mobileNumber': $("selector").val()
    }
})
```